# How do I make a wire link for veroboard quickly and accurately.

Tags: soldering, stripboard

I recently put together a prototype on veroboard. It was necessary to make several links from BTC to do the vertical connection between tracks.

[image: Project Board]

Is there a quick way of making wire links accurately?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Cut a piece of Veroboard as shown in the photograph this is the more expensive fibreglass board for longevity. The cut at the bottom goes halfway through a row of holes.

[image: tool]

Count up the number of holes you need from the bottom of the board and push the end of the wire through the hole.

[image: step1]

Bend the wire around the bottom of the board through the half hole.

[image: step2]

Cut off the end and you have a perfectly sized link.

[image: link]

Comment: +1. Clear and well explained, with correctly sized and focused photos. And a nice trick too!

Comment: Brilliant suggestion. I think I'll start using this idea when prototyping too!