# Bridge wire for soldering

Tags: pcb, soldering, components, wire

I saw in a video that the person was using something he called bridge wire to solder a pcb with.
I was wondering what kind if wire is used as a bridge to do the connection between components?

Here are 2 screenshots of what I was thinking of.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can also use Diode or resistor wire clippings which is tin plated steel (stronger) or tin plated copper. (faster heat conductor)

Comment: Related: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/55236/2028

Answer (score 3):

It is what is known as BTC an abbreviation for Bare Tinned Copper and is available by the reel. It is single strand for ease of use in getting it through the holes in the breadboard.

You also might want to take a look at [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/331828/how-do-i-make-a-wire-link-for-veroboard-quickly-and-accurately).

I also save and recycle the trimmed off ends of long leaded components it is essentially the same stuff.

Comment: The joy of mistaking tinned copper wire for solder can be yours!

Comment: You can make wire off a coil straight by pulling a length of it just past the yield point and it will be very straight.  Clip to length as required.  There are lead bending machines for resistors and such that can be used to preform the cut wires if you want.